# Boost spirit parser of Fortran printed doubles

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I am using [num_list3.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/num_list3.cpp) from Boost Spirit examples. I am testing the variety of the double types it can parse. I used the following list:

```
1.2,0.2
.2,5.
1.e+23,.23E4
0e+10
1.3D+3
```

I noticed that it fails on parsing the last number `1.3D+3`.

How could I set `D` as an exponent prefix of a double?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do that with Boost.Spirit. You just need to instantiate a [`real_parser`](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/real.html) with a custom policy that takes care of the "d|D" prefix. It could be as simple as:

```
template <typename Type>
struct fortran_policy : qi::real_policies<Type>
{
    template <typename Iterator>
    static bool parse_exp(Iterator& first, const Iterator& last)
    {
        if (first == last || (*first != 'e' && *first != 'E' && *first != 'd' && *first != 'D'))
            return false;
        ++first;
        return true;
    }
};
```

Then you would simply need to use:

```
qi::real_parser<double,fortran_policy<double>> double_;
```

without needing to change anything else(although that semantic action seems rather unnecessary).

[Live on ideone](http://ideone.com/wVzhtu)

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Although [FORTRAN apparently uses this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation), it's not widely used in any other context, and is not ISO-standardised scientific notation.

Comment: I'm afraid you (and both upvoters) may have missed the boost-spirit tag. What the asker wants is rather easy using `real_parser` with a custom policy.

Comment: @cv_and_he: That is simply not possible with the code the OP is asking about. You would have to write _different_ code.

Comment: Spirit parses text, so he does not expect that list to work directly in a CPP file, it will be in a string or a data file or whatever. Meaning that what is or isn't an ISO standardised scientific notation is irrelevant.

Comment: @cv_and_he You still need code to parse it differently than it is parsed now. From the question: _"it fails on parsing the last number"_ Write an answer if you wish.

Comment: It can be done better, but since I'm programming on a mobile phone... http://ideone.com/YJLuO9

Comment: @cv_and_he: You can always come back later and post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, but what I was looking for was a special parser, not a simple string scanner like `sscanf`.